# Is there a proper and clean alternative to Bit masking?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a 16bit long value, in which every two bits describe the configuration of an ADC channel (Bit0-1: Channel 0, Bit2-3: Channel 1, Bit4-5: Channel 2, ...).
Now I have a function to set the configuration of a specific Channel and i do this by masking the bits.

```cpp
enum class AdcChannel{
  CH0, CH1, CH2, ...
};

uint16_t SampleClass::setAdcChannelActive(uint16_t configReg, AdcChannel channel){
  configReg &= ~(3 << (channel *2));
  configReg |= CHANNEL_ACTIVE << (channel * 2);
  return configReg;
}
```

This works fine, but I wonder, if there is an better way, where no bitmasking is necessary.
In my mind is something like this:

```cpp
union C{
 uint16_t config;
 struct _ {
   uint16_t channel0:2;
   uint16_t channel1:2;
   uint16_t channel2:2;
   uint16_t channel3:2;
   uint16_t unused:8;
 } config_struct;
};

enum class AdcChannel{
  CH0, CH1, CH2, CH3
};

uint16_t setAdcChannelActive(uint16_t configReg, AdcChannel channel){
  C cfg = {configReg};
  cfg.config_struct.channel0 = CHANNEL_ACTIVE; //Here I should be able to use the channel parameter
  return cfg.config;
```

Comment: Checkout `std::bitfield` it might be suitable.

Comment: If you dont mind more typing, you can use `switch-case` statement: `switch(channel) { case CH0: channel0 = CHANNEL_ACTIVE; break; case CH1: channel1 = CHANNEL_ACTIVE; ... }`

Comment: @ALX23z I didn't found anything about std::bitfield ? Did you mean std::bitset ?

Comment: This question seems not clear about what is expected and  why the original code use configReg &= ~(3 << (channel *2)); configReg |= CHANNEL_ACTIVE << (channel * 2); Would you clarify ?

Comment: Structures with bit fields may be convenient, but considered not portable, as the layout is unspecified. In contrast, with bit operation it is portable, as you can know endianness and use known integer sizes.

Comment: @ALX23z Yes `std::bitset` would be a good option, if every channel would be represented by 1 bit (ex. 0 = off, 1 = on). Since I have two bit representing each channel, there would be some, in my opinion, ugly code to handle every of the two bit for its self.

Comment: @VainMan I also thought about this solution. But fact I don't like in this solution is that the code has to be changed if there is a different number of channels. With my first working example, i just have to change the enum in the header.

Comment: @WhiteWolf do you really need to have the structure compressed? Why not just use a byte for each channel? It's much simpler. While it takes more space it will probably be more efficient for most usages as there won't be any bit manipulations in the code.

Comment: @ALX23z I read the uint16_t with the config from a microcontroller where space is short.

Comment: using a struct with `uint16_t` is fine and portable (don't forget `#pragma pack` though). However, type punning through a union is UB. Initialize a local variable of your struct type and do `std::copy` to its address - it is the most safe way before C++20

Comment: you can also use your enum for bit fields: `enum class AddChannel : uint16_t`. This is type safe.

Comment: I'd be tempted to write the enumerators to have the appropriate mask values: `enum AdcChannel { CH0 = 0x03, Ch1 = 0x03 << 2, Ch2 = 0x03 << 4 };`

Comment: One thing if you read it from some other device, and another is how you use it in your code. You can always use packing/unpacking operations to transfer the configuration to the microcontroller.